# How can use an SSH tunnel with NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, ssh

My database is now hosted on a server which I only can reach using an SSH tunnel. My code uses NHibernate that worked before the move to the new server but afterwards I haven't been able to connect to the server.

Anyone have any example on how I can open an SSH tunnel and the create a session in NHibernate for the fetching and saving of data?

Comment: Alright, so to break it down, based on your comment on my initial answer below your question doesn't really concern NHibernate. The question you're really asking is: How to setup a SSH tunnel from C#/.Net?

Answer (score 0):

Update your connection string to target the local entrance to the SSH tunnel.

*Update*
It appears the question is really how to create an SSH tunnel from a .Net program. I'm not aware of any built-in functionality in .Net to do that. A quick google (https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ssh+c%23) turned up some possibilities), here's one of them: https://sshnet.codeplex.com/

There appears to be several other libraries judging from the google results. Have you tried any of these?

I suspect it might also be possible to have your program start e.g. PuTTY with suitable command line arguments. I haven't researched this and a library would be cleaner of course.

Comment: Sure I can change the connection to the localadress with the correct port and by that target the SSH tunnel but how do I setup the SSH tunnel from inside C#

And as an additional point, is there any problem with having the SSH tunnel up and running during the lifetime of the system or should I start the tunnel only while communicating with the database?